# Parse directory of XML files with R

Tags: xml, r

I'm parsing a directory of xml files downloaded from ClinicalTrials.gov and am having trouble extracting the data. I'm able to do it for a single file (NCT00006435.xml below) but can't figure out how to do it for multiple files.

```
library(XML)
# Download ct.gov query and extract xml files
ct<-tempfile()
dir.create("ctdir")
url<-"https://clinicaltrials.gov/search?term=neurofibromatosis-type-1&studyxml=true"
download.file(url, ct)
unzip(ct, exdir="ctdir")
files<-list.files("ctdir")
# Change the working directory so we don't have to worry about the filepath
setwd("ctdir")

# Extract data from one file and get it into a data frame
#xmlfile<-xmlTreeParse("NCT00006435.xml")
#xmltop<-xmlRoot(xmlfile)
#tags<-xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
#tags_df<-data.frame(t(tags),row.names=NULL)

# Extract data from each file and get it into a data frame
xmlfiles<-lapply(files,function(x) xmlTreeParse(x))
xmltop<-lapply(xmlfiles,function(x) xmlRoot(x))
tags<-???
```

How do I run through the list of files, looping through each tag in each file?

Comment: You need to actually download the individual files.  `xmlTreeParse()` operates on a _local_ file to extract the XML.  Currently, I believe that `files` just contains a list of matching filenames as they appear on the server.

Comment: Also an `xmlTreeParse()` does not automatically migrate to data frame but requires `xmlToDataFrame()`. It would be helpful to post sample xml.

Comment: Arrgh. ` object.size(xmltop) # 40 196 696 bytes`. Can we have an example that is "minimal"? And what is your understanding of the meaning of 'tag'?

Answer (score 0):

The top of str(xmltop) looks like:

```
List of 107
 $ :List of 40
  ..$ comment             : Named list()
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:5] "XMLCommentNode" "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" ...
  ..$ required_header     :List of 3
  .. ..$ download_date:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: Named list()
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:5] "XMLTextNode" "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" "oldClass"
  .. ..$ link_text    :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: Named list()
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:5] "XMLTextNode" "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" "oldClass"
  .. ..$ url          :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: Named list()
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:5] "XMLTextNode" "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" "oldClass"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" "oldClass"
  ..$ id_info             :List of 4
  .. ..$ org_study_id:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ text: Named list()
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:5] "XMLTextNode" "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" "oldClass"
```

So it's a list and you can "loop" over the top level of it with a simple `lapply`. If you want to use the code you have for your single node case, it's just:

```
tags<-lapply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
object.size(tags)
1618008 bytes
```

Still a rather unwieldily object. I repeat my suggestion that you find a more manageable example.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code in a function.

```
tags_df <- function(file){
  message("Loading ", file)
  #your code 
  xmlfile<-xmlTreeParse(file)
  xmltop<-xmlRoot(xmlfile)
  tags_l<-xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
  tags<-data.frame(t(tags_l),row.names=NULL)
  tags
}

tags<- lapply(files, tags_df)
```

Since you have one to many locations, keywords and other tags, combining the data.frames will return a mess with 260 columns below including location.1 to location.120.    I would replace your code with some specific xpath queries to get tags you really want into a comprehensible format.

```
x <- ldply(tags, "data.frame")
names(x)
```